# How can I add my email to my account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I couldn't remember my password, so I used the password recovery link, but was told that my email is not in the system. I also tried logging in with Google OpenID, since that's what I always use when given the chance, but it says it will create a new account. Oddly, my browser seems to remember my account (the present one, as evidenced by the presence of my gravatar); yet my profile lacks an Edit link, as though I'm not logged in.

Please excuse me for rambling -- I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess here, and probably mangle some terms - but your account for a site, and a profile for the network, are separate and disconnected.

As such, if it's a site you have never been to before - you can be logged into SE, but not have a site account, which sounds a lot like what you have. So just go ahead and create the account if you've never been to the site. Otherwise, you might need some dev assistance to sort things out - create the account, find your old account and ask the [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/377968)s to [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/377968) them.

It does feel like you used a google OpenID in the past and you don't have a username/password login.